# show animation on appearing a relativeview in android

Tags: android, animation

I am making a `search fragment` and it has a filter
when i click the filter button, i need the relativeview which has the filtration and its name is `dropdown` appears by animation "
but what happens is it doesn't appear and when i click again , it gives me the feeling like it's closing by animation "only when closing"
and when i **remove** the animation, it works properly
any help please

my xml is

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/dropdown"
        android:background="@color/filter_color"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/llay"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:visibility="gone">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtype"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sbtype"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Court"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/court"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Level"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/level"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:gravity="center" />

      <!--  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Age"
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:gravity="center" />-->
    </LinearLayout>
```

and the Fragment.java is

```
    private RelativeLayout dropdown;

        dropdown = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.dropdown);

         public void onClick(View v) {
                        // open drop menu
                        if (toggle==0){
        dropdown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dropdown.setAlpha(0.0f);
        dropdown.animate().translationY(dropdown.getHeight()).alpha(1.0f).start();
        }
          if (toggle==1){
  dropdown.animate().translationY(0);
        dropdown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

    if (toggle==0) toggle=1;else toggle=0;
```

Comment: You forgot to call start on second animation.

Comment: done
but it still not appear